# Button onclicked class changed but only the first click working

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, click

I would like to be set class `start1` from `start0` after clicking on Start button. After that I would like to change `start1` to `start2` after clicking on Start again and so on. Can you tell me what is the problem only the first click is working.

```js
    $(".start0").on("click", function () {
        $(".start0").attr("class", "btn btn-success start1");
    });
    $(".start1").on("click", function () {
        $(".start1").attr("class", "btn btn-success start2");
    });
    $(".start2").on("click", function () {
        $(".start2").attr("class", "btn btn-success start3");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success start0">Start</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use things like `.click()` or `.on()`, you're binding the click events to elements that satisfy the selector. "Find this element, give it this event".

But you're doing...

```
 $(".start1").on("click", function () {
        $(".start1").attr("class", "btn btn-success start2");
  });
```

...before `.start1` exists, and so on.

This is obfuscated and I suggest doing this differently, but in an effort to push you in the right direction, here would be your code reformatted to satisfy your intent:

```
$(".start0").on("click", function () {
    $(".start0").attr("class", "btn btn-success start1");
    $(".start1").on("click", function () {
        $(".start1").attr("class", "btn btn-success start2");
        $(".start2").on("click", function () {
            $(".start2").attr("class", "btn btn-success start3");
        });
    });
});
```

---

Personally, I might do something like this...

```
var i = 0;
$('.btn-success').click(function() {
   $(this).removeClass('start'+i);
   i++;
   $(this).addClass('start'+i);
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/s5f8a66o/)

Comment: Not a problem. Consider accepting the answer if you think it was a sufficient solution to your question c:

Comment: Cant yet, have to wait 1 minute :)

Comment: Thanks! Also, as I mentioned, consider checking out the JSfiddle link I just added. I think it may be a cleaner solution than binding so many events!

Answer (score 1):

Event handlers attached using the on() method will work for both current and future elements (like a new element created by a script). But your future elements .start1 etc. are not binded. 
so do this and you can understand by watching in console.

```js
$(".start0").on("click", function () {
  $(".start0").attr("class", "btn btn-success start1");
  console.log(1);
  $(".start1").on("click", function () {
    $(".start1").attr("class", "btn btn-success start2");
    console.log(2);
    $(".start2").on("click", function () {
      $(".start2").attr("class", "btn btn-success start3"); 
      console.log(3);
    });
  });  
});
```